# Issue plugging two arrays (first time passing multiple args) into a web3.py contract "Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types."

Tags: web3.py, python, polygon

Per the title, I'm having trouble passing in contract calls with multiple parameters. I can call balanceOf on this node just fine.

I'm using an infura node, and I'm attempting to call the more complex function "balanceOfBatch" which takes an address[] and uint256[] - presumably I was thinking I could pass a python list and a standard integer - however it's telling me the function invocation isn't being done properly.

The balanceOfBatch is the standard ERC-1155 function from Openzeppelin on a Polygon Mainnet contract.

Python web3.py code:

```
contract_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress("0x123")
web3_poly = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(polygon_mainnet_endpoint))
contract_object = web3_poly.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=my_abi)
addrs = [] # List of address strings (I tried ints too) e.g.: .append("0x123...")
ids = [] # list of ints (e.g. [1,2,3] - I tried numpy arrays, formatted strings (e.g. "[1,2,3]") - no success.
this_fails = contract_object.functions.balanceOfBatch(addrs, ids).call()
```

[image]

Error:

Could not identify the intended function with name `balanceOfBatch`, positional argument(s) of type `()` and keyword argument(s) of type `{'accounts': <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, 'ids': <class 'numpy.ndarray'>}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `balanceOfBatch`: ['balanceOfBatch(address[],uint256[])']
**Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the list of addrs was missing the web3.utils.toChecksumAddress formatting thus causing the invalid function arguments type (I struggled with even focusing in on the list of addresses).

What I was doing
addrs = []
...
addrs.append("0x123...")

The fix:
addrs = []
cleaned_addr =
addrs.append(web3.toChecksumAddress("0x123"))